# Othogonal Projection to 2D

Tags: 3d, projection, orthographic, orthogonal

How do I orthographically project a 3D set of points (x1,y1,z1...) to two dimensional space (x1,y1...) using a non-cardinal vector to represent the axis to be collapsed? I looked around and could find no satisfactory answer, and my linear mathematics handbook has only a projection to plane section, and not a projection to 2D space, and many answers that deal with projection are either perspective, or cardinal axis, the reason I need this is to calculate air-drag upon a falling body, with my vector being the body's velocity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick is to use a cardinal vector, because it makes this trivial to do. The idea behind most 3d packages is that the camera is always oriented one way in a cardinal orientation (usually -z). And the world is transformed to match the camera.

How do you handle non cardinal directions then? You handle them the same way, except that you transform the world into your cameras cardinal space. So what you do is you form a matrix for the plane with normal in negative z. Y and x axis being arbitrary orthogonal unit vectors of each other and z. The body is then transformed by the inverse matrix to the cardinal space of of your camera space. End result is a 3d space that is aligned so that reading first 2 coordinates yields your answer, and in case of perspective you still need to divide the points with their w value.

A old video example I made, visualizing all the steps to perspective, can be [found here (2.5M Quicktime movie)](http://users.tkk.fi/~joojala2/highend/3DCameraWorksLikeThis.mov)

In essence its just a question of choosing what you consider a good reference frame that's all. Its the same computation your just missing the non obvious part of having hierarchical transformation chains.

Comment: Thank-you, I knew I could inverse rotate it back to the cardinals, just thought it would be inefficient, as I plan on running this once every 16 Milli seconds or as close as I can get to it, and possibly on 1-40 objects at a time, but I guess there is no other way then, thanks for the help :-)

Comment: Yes but see most  of our hardware is optimized for matrix operations. Especially the graphics card that can do this for you with hundreds if not thousands of parallel processors. Besides this is a embarrassingly parallel problem. Also its not all they inefficient all the complex calculations are encoded and per-calculated in the matrix. So yes you can get tens of millions if not more of points transformed with a gfx card with those speeds.